# Integration issue in angular with aws-amplify for google sign up

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, google-signin, aws-amplify

I am trying to integrate with AWS-Amplify(^4.3.0) with angular-12 and typescript (4.3.5). I have configured amplify properly as mentioned in the documents but when I am trying to start the app got some amplify errors, Which are shown in below.

> Warning: D:\Google Sign-IN
> Demo\google-test\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\es\AuthenticationHelper.js
> depends on 'crypto-js/lib-typedarrays'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies
> can cause optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
>
> Warning: D:\Google Sign-IN
> Demo\google-test\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\es\Client.js
> depends on 'isomorphic-unfetch'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies  can
> cause optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@aws-amplify/storage/lib-esm/types/Storage.d.ts:44:46 -
> error TS2344: Type 'T[U]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args:
> any) => any'.    Type 'T["get"] | T["copy"] | T["put"] | T["remove"] |
> T["list"]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
> Type 'T["copy"]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
> Type '((src: StorageCopyTarget, dest: StorageCopyDestination, config?: any) => Promise) | ((src: StorageCopyTarget, dest:
> StorageCopyDestination, config?: any) => Promise<...>) | undefined' is
> not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
>
> 44 } : U extends 'copy' ? never : LastParameter<T[U]> & {
> ~~~~
>
> Type 'T["get"] | T["copy"] | T["put"] | T["remove"] | T["list"]' is
> not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
> Type 'T["copy"]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
> Type '((src: StorageCopyTarget, dest: StorageCopyDestination, config?: any) => Promise) | undefined' is not assignable to type
> '(...args: any) => any'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
>
> 58 declare type PickProviderOutput<DefaultOutput, T, api extends
> StorageProviderApi> = T extends StorageProvider ? T['getProviderName']
> extends 'AWSS3' ? Promise : ReturnType<T[api]> : T
> extends {

As per the [DOC](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/angular/#testing-your-api). After complete configure of AWS-Amplify with Cognito. I added the code below code in main.ts

```
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import aws_exports from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
```

Any help will be appreciated! Kindly let me know where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce this as well. This specifically happens to Angular 12 because it turns on `strict` mode [by default](https://angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-12#changes-and-deprecations-in-version-12), and `@aws-amplify/storage` type is not compliant with strict mode. You can bypass this error by setting

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictNullChecks": false,
  }
}
```

But this is worth creating an issue at their repo so that their storage type is compliant with strict mode if you're interested in doing so.

edit: found more scoped compilerOption for removing the error

Comment: @William Lee, Thank you so much for this great response. You are really a lifesaver for me at this moment. Thank you. Hit the question up, so it will help the community as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.....**  by adding below code snippet in to build section of your angular.json

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
      "crypto-js",
      "isomorphic-unfetch"

   ]
```